# Variable has strange behaviour when using event listener on JTable (Java with swing)

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener, mouselistener

Would really appreciate some help.

**Short version** Basically I can call a method with a hardcoded string as argument, but I can't use one specific global string variable (even though I can print it and checked that it is a string, and it is recognised)

**Long version:**
So I'm trying to get a function to work in a basic bank application and this drives me absolutely nuts.

I have classes for the logic of the bank, customers, and accounts. It's working as intended. The problem lies in the Gui class.

I'm using JTable to show the list of customers. Each customer has a personal number that I store in a global variable. I use this variable as an argument for the methods I'm calling. For example bank.findCustomer(personalNumber).

I can print the current selected personal number each time I click on a row in the table. That works fine. I have checked that it's indeed a string. But as soon as I create a Customer object to change the name (using a method from the customer class), I can't use the global variable of the selected personal number.

It seems so strange that I can hardcode the string but I can't pass the variable string.

My guess is that the string is somehow "locked up" in a synchronous(?) event or that the even listeners are in conflict. I have tried 1000 different things to get it to work. It feels like I'm bashing my head against a the wall...

I get the null-pointer exception when trying to call customer.setName() inside the actionPerformed method. If I use it outside this method, it works?

Here is the code:

```
class Gui implements ActionListener {
private BankLogic bank;
private JFrame frame;
protected JTable table;
protected JMenuBar menuBar;
protected JMenu mainMenu, customerMenu, accountMenu;
protected JPopupMenu popupMenu;
protected JMenuItem addCustomerItem, removeCustomerItem, editCustomerItem, showCustomersItem,
        createSavingsAccountItem, createCreditAccountItem, showAccountsItem,
        removeAccountItem, depositToAccountItem;
protected JButton refreshButton;
protected DefaultTableModel defModel;
String pNumOfCustomerSelected;
protected int accNumOfAccountSelected;
private JScrollPane scroll;
private ArrayList<String> customerDataList;
protected String test = "14";

Gui() {
    bank = new BankLogic();
    // dummy customers
    bank.createCustomer("Donald", "Duck", "12");
    bank.createCustomer("Dauda", "Dabo", "14");
    bank.createSavingsAccount("12");
    bank.createCreditAccount("12");
    // for testing
    pNumOfCustomerSelected = "12";



    // === MAIN MENU === //
    // Item for menu
    addCustomerItem = new JMenuItem("Add customer");
    addCustomerItem.addActionListener(this);
    // Menu to hold items
    mainMenu = new JMenu("Menu");
    // Menu bar to hold menu
    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    // Install components
    mainMenu.add(addCustomerItem);
    menuBar.add(mainMenu);



    // === POPUP MENU === //
    // Items for popup menu
    editCustomerItem = new JMenuItem("Edit customer name(s)");
    editCustomerItem.addActionListener(this);
    // Popup menu
    popupMenu = new JPopupMenu();
    // Install compeonents
    popupMenu.add(editCustomerItem);

    // === TABLE === //
    // Model for table
    defModel = new DefaultTableModel();
    defModel.addColumn("First name");
    defModel.addColumn("Last name");
    defModel.addColumn("Personal number");
    // Table
    table = new JTable(defModel);
    fillTable();

    // Scroll feature for table
    scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
    // refresh button
    refreshButton = new JButton("Refresh");
    refreshButton.addActionListener(this);
    // Install popup menu
    table.setComponentPopupMenu(popupMenu);
    // Install mouse listener
    table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {
            pNumOfCustomerSelected = (String) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 2);
            System.out.println(pNumOfCustomerSelected); // works fine
        }
    });


    // === MAIN FRAME === //
    // Main frame
    frame = new JFrame("Bank application");
    // Layout for frame
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    // Install components to frame
    frame.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    frame.add(refreshButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
    // Settings for main frame
    frame.setSize(400, 400);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
}

/**
 * Fills the customer table with data
 */

public void fillTable(){
    customerDataList = bank.getAllCustomers();
    // Filling the table with rows (of customer info)
    for(int i = 0; i < customerDataList.size(); i++){
        String customerInfo = customerDataList.get(i);
        String[] customerInfoComponents = splitString(customerInfo);

        Vector row = new Vector();
        row.add(customerInfoComponents[0]);
        row.add(customerInfoComponents[1]);
        row.add(customerInfoComponents[2]);

        defModel.addRow(row);
    }
}

/**
 * Clears the table rows
 */

public void clearTable(){
    int rowCount = defModel.getRowCount();
    if(rowCount > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            defModel.removeRow(0);
        }
    }
}

/**
 *
 * @param stringForProcess customer info
 * @return an array of the words in the string (separated by " ")
 */
String[] splitString(String stringForProcess){
    return stringForProcess.split("\\s+");
}

// action listener
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(e.getSource() == addCustomerItem)
        new AddCustomerWindow(bank, "Add customer");

    else if(e.getSource() == refreshButton){
        clearTable();
        fillTable();
    }
    else if(e.getSource() == editCustomerItem){
        Customer cust = bank.findCustomer(pNumOfCustomerSelected);

        // Customer customer = bank.findCustomer("12"); // This works fine???
        customer.setName("name");  // nullpointer
        customer.setSurName("surname");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It is not correct to use a MouseListener to monitor a JTable’s selection.  Use `table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener` for that.  If you print your `pNumOfCustomerSelected` field, you’ll probably discover that it’s null or has a value that you didn’t expect, due to your use of MouseListener.

Comment: Thx for the reply. Yea I used that before, but had trouble refreshing the table data since I have to use the listSelectionModel instead of the default model. Its still very strange that I can retrieve the data (I get the number printed each time I click on a row), but not use the variable later :/